# Instagram API not working with the credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, instagram, credentials

Im using the instagram-node module for the api. All the credentials are correct but i'm still getting an error.

```
var ig = require('instagram-node').instagram();

ig.use({ access_token: '84473***01.5220dbc.***d603520ec4758bf2a*******0076f' });
ig.use({ client_id: '522**bc9b3b14b47a76*******ed543a',
         client_secret: 'c0d**843eb634c7dbd0a4*******e442' });

ig.media_popular(function(err, medias, remaining, limit) {
    if (err) {throw err;}
    console.log(medias)
});
```

I get an error

```
 if (err) {throw err;}
                  ^

    Error: OAuthAccessTokenException: The access_token provided is invalid.
```

I could'nt find an answer online. Thanks.

Comment: Reading the docs, you have to use `access_token` OR `client_id/client_secret`, but not both.

Comment: Hey I get another error. `Error: APINotFoundError: invalid media id`

Comment: It says access token is invalid. Therefore use the below and try to generate your access token again. I think it will work then. http://instagram.pixelunion.net

Comment: That's an API specific problem. Check the documentation.